# How to Unit Test prints and logging at the same time in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

Assume we have a loop and we want to print messages and log certain outputs (warnings, and errors). These printed and logged outputs will be based on certain conditions. We want to make sure these outputs happened exactly 60 times, for example.

So my question is: How do you do unit tests so that you make sure that what was printed and logged was exactly 60 times(length of the loop), and no output was missed in the loop.

Comment: pytest has predefined fixtures for capturing logs and standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `print` output I suggest taking look at [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) which allow you to capture output, consider following simple example, let say you want test output of following function

```
def say_hello_world():
    print("hello world")
```

then you might do

```
import contextlib
import io
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f:
     say_hello_world()
output = f.getvalue()  # output is now str
print(output == "hello world\n")  # True
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. I want to capture items in a JSON file based on some logic inside a loop. What do you think is the best way for unit testing this? If you don't know the output ahead of time and the items are huge I think it is not possible to go with the approach you mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I am thinking this way: assume loop length 1000. logs and prints should be printed 1000 times. if printed 970 times it means some logic is wrong. So I want to make sure that  prints and logs were done exactly 1000 times